# VSCode :: How can I duplicate directories and files from within the file explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Ideally, I would right-click on the folder/directory or file I want to duplicate, choose "Duplicate" and, hopefully, would be asked in the same step to give the new duplicated file or directory a new name.

Looking at the current options, I couldn't find a way to do this on latest VSCode 1.19.1 (macOS):

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something? Is there other way to do this?

The more I use VSCode, the more I get used to it and, lately, I found myself barely needing to use the terminal provided in the Panel, or switching to a terminal app, for simple stuff like this.

Comment: I didn't find a way to do that. As a dirty workaround, you can ctrl+c / ctrl+v (well, cmd+c / cmd+v since you are on a mac) a file/folder in the explorer; this will create something like `myfile.1.txt` (which you can then rename with F2 -- if this is F2 on mac too)

Comment: Nice trick, didn't thought about trying that!

Comment: The right answer is below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52798391/586898

Comment: I agree, it's totally insane that "Duplicate" is not an option when right-clicking on a file...

Comment: @Vladan "Copy/Paste" is note the same as "Duplicate".

Comment: I appreciate the answer(s), but what a basic oversight in the core product ‍♂️

Comment: ctrl-c/v would be so much more useful, if it automatically followed up with the file renaming input -- instead of requiring another user interaction (clicks, other key) for giving the file it's intended filename.

Comment: Well, it not intuitive, but copying the folder and pasting, does indeed duplicate the folder. Works great in the text editor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about the good old CTRL+C and CTRL+V?

I just tried. If you click on a file then press CTRL+C, and then CTRL+V then you get a duplicate of the file named `[original name] copy.[ext]`

It's a mystery, though, why the duplicate file option is still not on the right-click menu after so many years.

**A little warning**: doing this will remove the content of the clipboard. So if you are in the middle of a copy-paste cycle, then make sure to save the clipboard content somewhere. Yes, it's inconvenient, but until MS decides to put in this basic action in the context menu (right-click) we need to deal with it.

Comment: I prefer it this way too. Less clicking around and no need to install an extension for such a basic action.

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: One reason I typically want a "Duplicate" action is when I already have something in my clipboard I don't want to overwrite. (This approach will overwrite what I have in the clipboard)

Comment: Exactly my point.. Sure, using the terminal or CTRL+C / V is something that we all know, thus rather not relevant to the question. But many times it is just easier of you can avoid a context switch, from GUI to terminal or otherwise. Else I would just stick to Vim / nano

Answer (score 67):

Marketplace extension [File Utils](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sleistner.vscode-fileutils):

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I hate it when people answer the question with "You don't need a duplicate option, just do these 3 other steps manually." That's not an answer. Especially when I need to do this action many times a day.

Comment: I was thinking the exact same. I love all these little VS Code plugins. Even if it does remove just a few steps it's worth it if it's something you do many times a day--the time adds up.

Comment: It will also add a "Duplicate" option on file explorer as well.

Answer (score 64):

To duplicate a file within a folder.

On the explorer pane:

- right click on the file,
- press copy
- now right click on the folder, and
- press paste
- the file will be duplicated into the same folder with "...-1" or " copy" appended to the file name

Comment: This is the exact and direct answer. I prefer not to bloat an editor with extensions that are really not essential.

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing until I got tired of it and looked for a better way.

Comment: Can't believe that file duplication is still not a feature in VSC.

Comment: As of 2020 July, suddenly I cannot use the normal copy paste within file explorer...

Comment: we know it... but we want a faster way to do it. Duplication by one key / click !

Comment: it's always the easiest solution. thank you!

Comment: 4 simple steps! Who needs one click when you can have 4‽

Comment: To clarify, the advantage of duplication over copy/paste is that copying clears any text from the clipboard. That means you have to switch back to the original file after copying to copy the text again and rename the copied file with that text. Duplication allows you to duplicate the file and immediately rename with text from the clipboard.

Comment: That's obvious but not what we'd like.

Answer (score 19):

A somewhat old issue now but as I try to avoid installing too many extensions this may be helpful to others wanting to avoid the same. Also, as there's a strong chance this is a context in which you're using a mouse/trackpad (as opposed to keyboard), the normally fantastic 'do everything' quick menu thing (or whatever `Shift + CMD + P` is called) is probably not a great solution...

1. Hold down `Alt`. (Note: You can actually do this during step 2 if preferred).
2. Drag the file onto the folder it is already in (during drag the cursor will have a green plus icon).
3. Release the file where you want it to be (doesn't actually have to be the same folder).
4. The file will be duplicated with the filename `{original-filename} copy.{original-extension}`.
5. Click on the file again.
6. Hit enter/return to edit the filename.

All the above sounds much more onerous than it really is. I find it quicker than right-clicking and momentarily finding/navigating to a menu option, especially if that menu option is not a native one.

Comment: This is very convenient!

Comment: for me it is CTRL not alt to duplicate a file.

Comment: This is the one. The primary reason for wanting to avoid copy/paste (as in other answers) is in the scenario that you have already got a load of text copied to your clipboard that you don't want to loose.

Comment: Given that I do in fact use a mouse, this is so much easier. And so obvious in hindsight. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, this is the simplest answer. No extra extensions needed. alt + click and drag.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works perfectly on Mac

Answer (score 18):

The "[Duplicate action](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-duplicate)" extension will allow you to right click and choose duplicate as you described.

[image]

Comment: There are obviously a few alternatives - I've added an image of what the file dialog looks like with the 'duplicate' action installed. It's been core functionality in most other editors I've used.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Atleast in Linux, holding down `Ctrl` and dragging the file into the required directory should do the trick. No `Ctrl+C` `Ctrl+V` required.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, since VS Code still does not allow this in 2022:

Install the [multi-command package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).
Then, in your `keybindings.json` add the following:

```
    {
        "key": "cmd+d",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": {
            "sequence": [
                "filesExplorer.copy",
                "filesExplorer.paste"
            ]
        },
        "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus && !explorerResourceIsRoot && !inputFocus"
    }
```

Afterwards, you can **press `CMD + D` to duplicate a file** or folder.

You may want to add `"renameFile"` into the sequence to directly rename the duplicate. Of course, this works just as well with `ctrl` instead of `cmd`.

Comment: Nice solution to this problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+C
CTRL+V
F2
*type new name*
ENTER
*opens in editor*

Similar to above but with an extra couple of things